# I want to simplify repeated calls in my init.el file

Tags: functions, funcall

I've got a lot of:

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(show-paren-mode 1)
```

which I'd like to collapse into:

```
(mapcar (lambda (fn) (fn 1)) '(desktop-save-mode show-paren-mode))
```

but I get an error:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: fn
```

How can I call a list of functions with the same argument?

Comment: You don't need to pass `1` to enable a minor mode, so `(mapc #'funcall '(...))` will do the trick.

Comment: I'm certain this is a duplicate (for learning about `funcall` and friends), but I seem to be failing at searching.  Refer to `C-h i g (elisp)Calling Functions` for the details.

Answer (score 2):

`(mapcar (lambda (fn) (funcall fn  1)) '(desktop-save-mode show-paren-mode))`

Answer (score -3):

```
desktop-save-mode
```

is defined thusly:

```
(define-minor-mode desktop-save-mode
```

so its not a function...

Comment: I'd still like to clean up my init file, any suggestions on how I could do that?

Comment: Hmm... `define-minor-mode` defines a function (and a variable as well), so yes it *is* a function.